# Deciphering Kawaii Writing

Tags: kanji, handwriting, writing-identification, written-language

I was wondering if anyone knew how to read Kawaii writing and if there is any guide to help us read them?

For example the following is I believe an omake or bonus page and it's not the first time I encounter these and I find them very hard to read...

[image]

From what I understand **with bold character where I'm not sure** where I don't understand, it's possible that everything I read may be wrong because it feels SO difficult to read these.

オマケ**?**な
**甘木公半**
**(陪めの話**だから
**甘**いのがかきたつなったっさ）

I wish there were books or other resources that could help with these bizarre ways of writing..

Thanks in advance to anyone that may shed some light into these for me, especially if you can help me understand how to read these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handwriting is always harder to read, but I think in your case you miss practice. For me, reading difficult handwriting comes down to recognizing which strokes are used, and based on their number and approximate order, find the corresponding character. I am often stumped by unknown handwritten characters.

The most glaring issues with what you've come up so far:

- 松 and not 木公 : You should be able to tell by the size and lack of spacing that it is one character.
- 暗 and not 陪 : As the leftmost stroke does not protrude from the key, it is probably 日. You also missed a stroke on the inside.

In your case I think this is what's written:

> オマケ的な甘松半 (暗めの話だから甘いのがかきたくなったのさ）

Comment: As an added note, it can help to read handwriting to practice proper stroke order and writing oneself. The 的 is pretty easy to read if you've seen how it comes out by handwriting several times.

Comment: 多分「松半」は[これ](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E6%9D%BE%E5%8D%8A)ですかね。"harry/draco" 的な。

Comment: Thanks guys! I understand my mistakes now, it's just that when it's handwritten I seem to forget "space". I'm not used to reading handwritten materials so well, I lack practice in that area.